# Errors while Booting

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

When I boot I get the following Messages (maybe some typos in it)

```
[ 1.836733] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 
[ 1.836911] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 
[ 1.836995] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 
[ 1.837048] blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash (-13) 
[ 1.870416] /deu/root: Can't open b1ockdev
[ 1.870468] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) 
[ 1.870498] CPU: 2 PID : 1 Comm : swapper/0 Not tainted 6.2.0-32-generic #32-Ubuntu 
[ 1.870521] Hardware name: MEDION E3216 MD61800/MT13A, BIOS V2.0.13_P2S0T1P1F3G2C2 05/11/2018 
[ 1.870544] Call Trace: 
[ 1.870555] <TASK> 
[ 1.870567] dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70 
[ 1.870586] dumpstack+Ox10/0x20 
[ 1.870598] panic+Ox37b/Ox3cO 
[ 1.870615] mount_block_root+Ox2c9/0x2d0 
[ 1.870632] mount_root+Ox83/OxbO 
[ 1.870645] prepare_namespace+Oxf5/0x200 
[ 1.8706591 kernel_init_freeable+Oxle5/0x220 
[ 1.870674] __pfx_kernel_init+Ox10/0x10 
[ 1.870692] kernel_init+Ox1b/Ox200 
[ 1.870706] pfx_kernel_init+Ox10/0x10 
[ 1.870739] ret_from_fork+Ox2c/Ox50 
[ 1.870755] </TASK> 
[ 1.870872] Kernel Offset: Ox19000000 from Oxffffffff81000000 (relocation range: Oxffffffff80000000-Oxffffffffbfffffff) 
[ 1.870908] --I end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) 1---
```

```
I can only boot into old Kernel. I cannot open a terminal-window.
```

Comment: Pls. help! Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The odd thing is the "block(0,°)" at the very end. Check you grub config for this. The ° should be a number -depending on your setup.

Comment: it actually is "block(0,0)".
i took a picture of the screen with a camera and then did ocr. Overseen it.
Thank you for answering and fixing the format. I tried but couldn't figure it out.